# Issue trying to affect views inside a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, android-recyclerview

So, I am currently building an Android app using Android studio. I am building it using Kotlin and the particular points regarding the app are:

- I am using `BottomNavigationView` with a `NavFragmentView` using the `Navigation Graph`. That part is working fine.
- I have 5 main fragments which are the main sections of the app and basically when you tap on one of the items of the `BottonNavigationView` the correct fragment gets pulled to the main `NavFragmentView`.

I am currently stuck implementing a `RecyclerView` that displays sort of a calendar using a `GridLayout`.

I have prepared the user interface, and filled the `RecyclerView` with static data from a list inside my adapter for the `RecyclerView`.

The next thing I did was to obtain my JSON data from my API using `OkHTTP` and afterwards give it format using `GSON`. Everything up to this point works fine, the JSON gets correctly formatted and obtained. The trouble starts when I want to pass it to the adapter.

I had some trouble accessing stuff before that, because as I am new to Kotlin and Android I was having trouble accessing stuff directly from the fragment, but then I found out that I can assign the main view of the fragment to a variable and refer to it from there. That part partly fixed my issues. So, my code is something like this:

**MesFragment.kt - this is the Kotlin file for my fragment, as you can see I assign my main view to the `mesView` variable, I had to create it outside of the main function, because when trying to assign the adapter in the `fetchMes()` function it had no access to the view**

```
class MesFragment : Fragment() {

    var mesView : View? = null

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {

        mesView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_mes, container, false)
        //mesView.calendario_mes.adapter = MesAdapter()

        fetchInfoMes("201905")

        return mesView

    }


    fun fetchInfoMes(mes: String) {
        val url = "https://www.myoriginalsite.com/api/mes/"+ mes +"/-0500/norte"

        val request = Request.Builder().url(url).build()

        val client = OkHttpClient()
        client.newCall(request).enqueue(object: Callback {

            override fun onResponse(call: Call, response: Response) {
                var body = response.body()?.string()

                val gson = GsonBuilder().create()

                val mesFeed : List<FechaCompleta> = gson.fromJson(body, object: TypeToken<List<FechaCompleta>>() {}.type)

                mesView?.calendario_mes?.adapter = MesAdapter(mesFeed)
            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call, e: IOException) {
                println("Error")
            }

        })
    }

}

class FechaCompleta(val vacia: Boolean, val imagen_signo: String, val imagen_luna: String, val fecha: String, val dia: String, val id_entrada: Int)
```

**MesAdapter.kt - this is my adapter, as you can see I have commented my static list and the only UI change I am trying to do is the `mes_fecha.text`**

```
class MesAdapter(val mesFeed: List<FechaCompleta>): RecyclerView.Adapter<MesViewHolder>() {

    //val list = listOf<String>("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31")

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MesViewHolder {
        val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent?.context)
        val cell = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.celda_mes_layout, parent, false)

        return MesViewHolder(cell)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return mesFeed.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MesViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder?.view?.mes_fecha.text = mesFeed[position].dia
    }

}

class MesViewHolder(val view: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {

}
```

Once I open the fragment the app closes and I get this error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: OkHttp Dispatcher
    Process: com.testing.fragmentapp, PID: 8148
    android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
```

Comment: don't call the view from a thread that is not the UI thread? The error message is quite specific, I assume it also tells you the exact line where you're trying to access it from not-the-ui-thread.

Comment: I did find that in normal cases, using a `runOnUiThread { }` block would do the trick, but for some reason it won't work in my context, I guess it's related to the fragment thing. Is there a way to run that block from my context?

Comment: I literally add it and it turns red, and marks an error.

Comment: Any particular reason why you're not using Retrofit for fetching that JSON list? if you did, then Retrofit's callback is actually invoked on the UI thread; it's OkHttp that knows absolutely nothing about Android and therefore can't go back to the UI thread on its own. If you use Retrofit, you won't have this problem with `enqueue`. Also, if you want to post to the UI thread (and you don't have `view.post {` or `activity.runOnUiThread {` nearby), then you can always create a `private val handler = Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())` and do `handler.post {`.

Comment: So, what would be the solution? Switch my http client to Retrofit and then?

Comment: or post to a handler and set the adapter in that lambda

Comment: Could you point me to a specific tutorial on how to do that or how to fix the above situation. As I mentioned I am new to this and I am not sure how the lambda thing works or how to post to a handler.

Comment: `private val handler = Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()); handler.post { /* do things here */ }` like I said above

Comment: @EpicPandaForce so, the `handler` would be inside the `onBindViewHolder` in the Adapter or inside the API call in `fethInfoMes` function?

Comment: Ok, I managed to fix this switching to Retrofit2, the code was basically the same or even easier than Okhttp3. Thanks for the advice, could you put it as an answer @EpicPandaForce?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OkHttpClient invokes the callback on the background thread.

So you should either:

1.) use Retrofit instead, which invokes your callback on the UI thread

2.) go back to the UI thread from your background thread using a Handler

```
private val handler = Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())

call.enqueue(object: Callback {
        override fun onResponse(call: Call, response: Response) {
            var body = response.body()?.string()

            val gson = GsonBuilder().create()

            val mesFeed : List<FechaCompleta> = gson.fromJson(body, object: TypeToken<List<FechaCompleta>>() {}.type)

            handler.post {
                mesView?.calendario_mes?.adapter = MesAdapter(mesFeed)
            }
        }

        override fun onFailure(call: Call, e: IOException) {
            println("Error")
        }
})
```

Comment: I ended up using the first option with minimum changes in code and it worked perfectly.